# Overlapping issue in IE

Tags: html, css

One problem about the layout issue in IE. With the increase of dynamically added elements, the inner 'dynamicdiv' in the 'body' section should overlap the footer section. But now some elements are overlapped and hid by 'footer' section.

The position of outer divs are relative and that of the inner div is absolute. The code works in FF/Chrome.

```
<div id='top' style='position: relative;' />
<div id='body' style='position: relative;  left: 44px; top: 95px; width: 275px; z-index:99'> 
  <div id = 'dynamicdiv' style='position: absolute; ...'> 
     multiple div sections will be dynamically added here during the runtime. 
  </div>
</div>
<div id='footer' style='position: relative; background-color:red;  z-index:1' />
```

Adding the z-index does not work.

How to show all elements in 'dynamicdiv' by overlapping the 'footer' section?

Thanks

Comment: Could you add proper code, so that one can try it. Instead of writing own headers and footers and then helping you with your code. May be you can put it in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code http://jsfiddle.net/hCkjA/42/

body div does not contain z-index
footer has lower z-index than dynamic div.
Also If you want to stick the footer to the bottom then add

```
#footer{ bottom:0px;}
```

Hope it helps.